# How do I take a String I appended to an array of Strings and then store it permanently into memory with Swift 2?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2, xcode7

I've been trying to create a simple app that has a preexisting array of Strings, and when inside of a UIAlertController, you can add more items to the list through the text box. I've tried NSUserDefault declarations all over the place, but none of these objects get stored into memory. This is my ViewController class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var names = ["Stow the TV antenna", "Stow the awning", "Retract stabilizer jacks", "Store wood blocks", "Plug in trailer lights", "Hookup the breakaway chains", "Make sure the trailer lights work", "Drain waste tanks and store hose", "Unplug sources of electrical power", "Stow chairs, dog rope, etc.", "Douse the campfire completely", "Stow the TV", "Ensure the fridge is closed and stable", "Switch fridge to gas", "Close all compartments", "Pick up everything", "Close the vents and windows", "Turn off the water pump"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return names.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    cell.name.text = names[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

@IBAction func pressAdd(sender: AnyObject) {
    // Display the warning
    displayAddItem("Add Tasks", message: "Add more tasks to the list")
}

@IBAction func pressShare(sender: AnyObject) {
    // Check to see if table is empty
    if (names.isEmpty) {
        displayAlert("Warning", message: "Your list has no tasks!")
    }

        // If there are contents
    else {
        displayShareSheet("Share your list")
    }
}

func displayAlert(title: String, message: String) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style:
        .Default, handler: nil))
    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: {})
    return
}

func displayShareSheet(shareContent:String) {
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareContent as NSString], applicationActivities: nil)
    presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: {})
}

func displayAddItem(title: String, message: String) {
    var inputTextField: UITextField?

    let addItemController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)

    addItemController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "Add a task"
        inputTextField = textField

    }

    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
        alert -> Void in
        if (inputTextField!.text != "") {

            if let itemText = inputTextField {
                let stringToAdd = itemText.text
                self.names.append(stringToAdd!)
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(self.names, forKey: "arr")
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

    })

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)


    addItemController.addAction(saveAction)
    addItemController.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.presentViewController(addItemController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        names.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(names, forKey: "arr")
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Using what I've got, how can I use my saveAction to write the String from the textField to append to my "names" array and store it permanently in memory? Thanks!

Comment: You're using `setObject` in two different places, and I don't see where you retrieve the data... Looks like some sort of "brain typo" to me. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me that you're not retrieving the info from NSUserDefaults. To do this you need to call:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("arr")
```

Having said that, NSUserDefaults is intended to be a place to save user preferences and not persist business objects.

If this is going to scale I'd suggest you to take a look at other alternatives to persist data like [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html) or [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/).

Comment: I'm guessing that he's just saving the info but not retrieving it (I don't see any part where he's actually getting the info), that's why I'm suggesting to use synchronize since it looks by the structure of his code that he wants to save and immediately retrieve it, I might be wrong though and in that case as you pointed out using synchronize doesn't solve any issues ;) I'll update.

Comment: How would you suggest going about this using Core Data then?

Comment: You can either go to the official docs (linked in my answer) or look for tutorials online about Core Data. Something like [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-managed-objects-and-fetch-requests--cms-21284) might be useful

Answer (score -1):

to store data on a iOS device you have to use CoreData or alternative you have to solve this problem with a .csv data. CoreData is a Database developed by Apple for iOS applications to store datas permanently and a .csv Data is not a "fine" solution but pretty much simpler than CoreData. So you have to choose wich one of this solutions sounds better for you ;) I'm sure you find a lot of tutorials for this Topic on YouTube or at Google. Hope I could help with this information good luck! ;)